# Multiple jQuery Accordions are interfering with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have created some horizontally sliding accordions that i wish to use. If i only have one accordion then it works perfectly, but if i add in a second one then they interfere with each other.

e.g. Clicking one tab on the first accordion will open a tab on the second accordion.

I need them to be independent of each other somehow.

Here is a snippet of my js, the rest is in the jsfiddle if you would be kind enough to take a look.

```
var totalTabWidth = 0;
function accord(){
$("*[accordionHeditor='true']").not('[rendered]').each(function(){
    activePanel = $(this).find("div.accPanel:first");

        $(this).find(".accPanel").each(function(){
          totalTabWidth += parseInt($(this).find(".blue").css("width").replace("px", ""));
        });

        $(activePanel).animate({width: (parseInt($(activePanel).parent().css("width").replace("px")) - totalTabWidth).toString() + "px"}, 300);
        $(activePanel).parent().find('.accPanel').removeClass('active');
        $(activePanel).addClass('active');

        $(this).on('click', '.accPanel', function(e){
            if( ! $(this).is('.active') ){
            $(activePanel).animate({width: "44px"}, 300);
            $(this).animate({width: (parseInt($(this).parent().css("width").replace("px")) - totalTabWidth).toString() + "px"}, 300);
            $(this).parent().find('.accPanel').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            activePanel = this;
           };
         });

      $(this).attr("rendered", "1");
 });
}

accord();
```

There is an example below with all of my code in this fiddle:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/rsmith93/fhwmea8c/
```

Any help at all is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to uniquely identify the accordions by id. Try writing separate click events for the two accordions.

Below is an example(that i've used in my project before) to dynamically add a text box and set unique attributes.
You can follow the same for your accordion.

```
function add() {

    j++;
        //Create an input type dynamically.
        var element = document.createElement("input");
        var element2 = document.createElement("br");

        //Assign different attributes to the element.
        element.setAttribute("type", "text");
        element.setAttribute("id", j);
        element.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
        element.setAttribute("name", j);
        element.setAttribute("onblur", "addPreferedLocation()");
        element.setAttribute("placeholder", " Preference"+" "+j);


        var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

        //Append the element in page (in span).
        foo.appendChild(element);
        foo.appendChild(element2);



}
```

Comment: For what im trying to achieve the user will actually add these accordions to a page and can add as many as they want, so i wont be able to hard code the onclick events for each one. Thanks though

Comment: In that case, you can generate the id by auto incrementing a numeric variable and assigning it to the accordion as its id. Then you can get the id from the click event.

Comment: Thanks, would you be able to provide a simple example of how to go about this?